# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot: /dev/sda5 clean, 525049/30343168 files, 13164811/121342720 blocks

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, recovery-mode

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on my computer and it uses NVIDIA drivers. When I enter Ububtu this message appears:

/dev/sda5 clean, 525049/30343168 files, 13164811/121342720 blocks

For fixing this problem, I've already tried the solution below:

["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

But it didn't work. I've run following commands on recovery mode:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

It seems like the problem is not due to nvidia drivers. What could be the cause of this problem and how can I solve it?

UPDATE:
I removed all the nvidia packages

sudo apt-get purge package_name

Then with autoinstall, I reinstall them

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

I still get THE SAME message.

Also, I checked disk with df -H command. NONE of the filesystems were in 100% use.

Comment: Did you try other Nvidia install methods before the ubuntu-drivers?  You may still have leftovers from earlier installs, see the packages with nvidia in their name by running 
dpkg -l |grep nvidia   Purge the lines beginning with rc if any (leftovers, removed but config files still around). Check /etc/modprobe.d files for any leftover lines blacklisting nvidia (except nvidiafb is ok to blacklist).

Comment: There were some rc files left I removed them, but still it didn't work. There are some li files do I need to delete them also?

Comment: In that case I'd need to run sudo apt-get purge *nvidia* right?

Comment: The ii packages are the fully installed ones.  You may add to your original posting for replies, comments may be deleted at some point -- and also better formatting is available to you.  (I assume you typed \*nvidia\* but it came out italics. You can purge the libnvidia\* but asterisk on the command line may always produce output you do not expect (if there are any files in your current directory that match).

Comment: I deleted all of them and reinstall them but I get the same thing.

Comment: Which Nvidia drivers get installed, the 515?  the sda5 clean message is normal and not an error.  Did you ensure no "blacklist nviida..." exists in any file in /etc/modprobe.d files (except nvidiafb is OK to blacklist)?  What Nvidia hardware are you running? Is it enabled in the UEFI Settings? Looks like the "Black screen at login" which can be caused by many things preventing the normal video from starting.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, we need to diagnose the issue further, it might have nothing to do with nvidia drivers but something is causing the system to hang.  To start with in recovery mode run
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
file and remove the quiet flag from the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT then run

`sudo update-grub`

Reboot and you should see a lot more messages and maybe you might see what your problem is.  Maybe its a stop job that is hanging indefinitely but it should give you the name.

If you cannot get into recovery mode or the quiet option is not in that file, when you are in grub, hit e on the MAIN ubuntu option, then find the line that starts with linux, there should be a quiet flag on that line, remove it, and it should do the same as above, but it is only temporary and the quiet flag will come back after a reboot

Comment: Well, I deleted quiet flag it didn't show me any error or it didn't stuck at any message. At the end, on the screen, there is one small line at top left side of the display and no message.

Comment: This method seems like did not work. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your disk isn't full.

Linux will not boot and stop at that message if your root filesystem is 100% full.

Also post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: I checked disk with df command. None of the filesystems was in 100% use.

Comment: But when I enter fsck on recovery mode I get this message below

Comment: /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS : No such file or directory

Comment: And I can't enter /var/log/Xorg.0.log permission denied

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: By the way, I realized that I had problem woth swapfile which shows me memory is full.