# Ubuntu 20.04- /dev/sda5:clean 242499/30498818 files, 10395890/123098599 blocks

Tags: upgrade

Since I've tried to upgrade my ubuntu 22.04 to ubuntu 24 proposed by ubuntu itself, the result is that each time the system tries to load, appears this error message:
"/dev/sda5:clean 242499/30498818 files, 10395890/123098599 blocks" and stops progressing.

I've tried different solutions of the same problem proposed on this site,`sudo apt-get purge nvidia sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` also `sudo apt install gdm3`
also `sudo apt updat sudo apt clean sudo apte autoremove sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade sudo dpkg --configure -a sudo apt install -f`
but without any result.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: The newest version of Ubuntu in full release is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. There is no 24. Where are you seeing you should be trying to install this non existent version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: Where should I type this commands in live DVD terminal or in Recovery Mode root terminal?