# Upgrade from 20.04 (Desktop) to 22.04 (Desktop) gone wrong

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

I upgraded my system from 20.04 (Desktop) to 22.04 (Desktop).
I followed the installation of the pop-up screen `Do you want to upgrade to 22.04`. In the last step, there was a `Restart Required`, which left me with the blinking screen I took a photo of.

I did not experience any errors of any kind during the installation.

Has anyone seen this kind of error before? And maybe have an idea how I go about fixing it?

The text on the photo[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfXq3.jpg) says:

```
[0.125709] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS

/dev/sda5: clean, 201894/30498816 files, 6244232/121964800 blocks

[20.488414]
```

Comment: I haven't used this computer in quite a while so I don't know the details completely of the system that was on there but I'll do my best to state what I think Is correct.

I'm pretty certain there was a 20.04 (Desktop) on there that I then followed the installer, the thing that pops up "Do you want to upgrade to 22.04", and in the last step there was a "restart required" which ended in this blinking screen.

No errors I saw throughout the install.

Comment: I changed the title and question. Hope it's better now!

Comment: Usually the statement "Long time not used" leads me to Bios Battery empty. Empty battery can lead to all kind of strange behavior.

Comment: @Marco, interesting. I did boot this computer up normally yesterday and It was OK with 20.04. Do you believe the BIOS battery could have somehow drained in the process of upgrading the system?

Comment: So new info on this: I can boot if I go through recovery mode (holding down shift while turning on the computer, going into advanced options, and choosing recovery mode). There I ran dpkg and then just normal boot, and it booted fine, and I can use the machine normally.

But when I restart it I get the same black screen—blinking this text again.

Comment: Please add additional detail to your question; this is a Q&A site (*Question & Answer* site) and **not a forum**. Comments are intended to be only that, comments to the original question, or a prior commentator & **not** for information from the *Original Poster* (OP) as that is deemed important detail & belongs in the Question (as it's useful for answers to consider; comments are not considered in answers, as they answer only the question).  I realize you're new, but Forums & Q&A sites differ in approach..  Forums require you to read the whole thread; here only the Question matters

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: Have you tried booting from flash stick with 22.04? Is secure boot disabled?