# "/dev/sda6: Clean, 230564/2318336 files, 3664252/9250048 blocks" at Ubuntu boot page with some ACPI BIOS errors

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap

I completely removed my 8GB swap and added its volume to my root partition. Now I just have root and home partitions. When I boot, I see some unimportant ACPI BIOS Errors followed by a line that says `/dev/sda6: Clean, 230564/2318336 files, 3664252/9250048 blocks` (`/dev/sda6` is my root partition).

[image]

What is this line for? is there any problem with my disk partitions? How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)