# I am stuck at this after reboot: /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 958904/21823488 files, 86223682/87291141 blocks

Tags: boot

[image]

It always stuck at this stage with the:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 958904/21823488 files, 86223682/87291141 blocks
```

Comment: We currently have almost no details... We don't know what OS/product/release you're using (ie. which Ubuntu product), nor if this new install, or you installed some package in the last session before this issue occurred (*what changes you made will impact the best/easiest fix and only the operator will know what that is*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: This has been asked in many forms here previously, and I've linked to the most populated duplicate. It seems the consensus is that this is most often an NVidia driver problem, where you have to boot into safe mode, and re-install NVidia drivers.