# Laptop can only boot into Ubuntu 22.04 LTS through recovery mode, screen will freeze during normal boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04, usb-installation

#### Background

Hello all, I'm trying to revive an old laptop (HP ProBook 4540s) that was running an old version of Windows 10. This is my first time running Linux on a PC (outside of some small virtual machines). I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04, flashed it onto a USB using balenaEtcher, and installed the OS onto the laptop from there. My BIOS was configured to boot with UEFI. On booting from USB, I was given a few options at the GNU GRUB menu. I first noticed something wrong when my computer would freeze up after selecting the top `Ubuntu` option. I went through several restarts before deciding to go with `Ubuntu (safe graphics)`. My laptop was able to go through the regular Ubuntu installation process after this.

[Options On First Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmcAg.png)

---

#### Main Issue

After installing Ubuntu and restarting the laptop, I noticed a few things. A line popped up that looks like:

```
/dev/sda3: clean, xx/xx files, xx/xx blocks
```

The cursor would blink for a while, and then completely freeze. I then tried to reboot the computer in recovery mode, and resume the boot from there. I was able to get onto the desktop, complete the setup, and use Ubuntu like normal (i.e., installing applications, browsing). Unfortunately, I can ONLY complete the boot through recovery mode. Trying to boot normally causes the computer to completely freeze and become unresponsive after the same line. I can't even access TTY with ctrl+alt+f2 or other shortcuts. I've looked at all the solutions under [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w), but haven't found success with any of them. I went down a rabbit hole thinking it was a graphics issue (and it might still be), but I couldn't find a solution that worked since I don't have an Nvidia card. I've looked for additional drivers in Ubuntu's software updater, but nothing comes up. I've even tried a fresh install and ran into the same exact issues. I'd appreciate any thoughts on what be going on, and how I might be able to fix this problem.

Anyway, I'll list some more relevant information below.

---

#### More Information

**Specs:**

After booting through recovery mode, using `inxi -G`, I get:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: N/A
  Device-2 AMD Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] driver: N/A
  Display server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: vesa
    unloaded: fbdev, modesetting gpu: N/A resolution 1366x768-76Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mwsa 22.2.5
```

And the rest of the specs:

- Memory: 8.0 GiB
- Processor: Intel Core i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60 GHz x 4
- Graphics llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits) ** I assume this is because it's booted through recovery?**
- Disk Capacity: 750.2 GB
- OS Type: 64-bit
- GNOME Version: 42.5
- Windowing System: X11

**Removing `quiet splash` from GNU bootup script**:

I see a bunch of processes tagged with `[  OK  ]`, but the computer consistently freezes after

```
Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status
```

The screen becomes unresponsive again, and no keyboard shortcuts work. I have to power off from here to reboot. I've actually noticed that, during this process, the font type changes before freezing, which is odd.

**gdm3**

After booting through recovery mode, and using `systemctl status display-manager`, I see that `gdm.service` is loaded and active.

If I go to the advanced options for Ubuntu during the boot, and use the same command, I can see that `gdm.service` is loaded but it's inactive (dead). I have no idea if this is expected, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

---

I can't think of any other things to share right now, but I can definitely grab more info/outputs if more info is needed. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve my own problem after fiddling around with the BIOS settings. I assumed the whole issue had to deal with my graphics driver or something. So, in my BIOS settings, I disabled switchable graphics in the device configurations menu. After that my computer has booted up normally and works perfectly as expected now.

I guess it had to do with my computer trying to mess with both the Intel and the AMD graphics drivers during boot.

And guess what, I can change my brightness again!