# Dual Boot Ubuntu alongside windows 11 /dev/sdb6: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/yyy blocks

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, nvidia

I am attempting to install Ubuntu alongside windows 11. When I load from grub, ubuntu, a black screen appears which says

> /dev/sdb6: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/yyy blocks

what does this mean and how can I fix it so that Ubuntu starts without having to go into recovery mode.

I thought it was related to the NVIDIA drivers as when I go into recovery mode all the icons are stretched (They still are and i cant change the screen resolution). I tried reinstalling the drivers using the following

```
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-settings
```

I then put in my MOK key when the machine restarted but I'm back to the error message above

I tried all the suggestions on the page ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Does anyone know of any other ways i can trouble shoot?

Thanks

Specs
NVIDIA RTX 4080
Motherboard MS-7D25

Comment: That is not an error. That is just saying that your file system is ok and you do not need to run any repairs like e2fsck.  I do not have nVidia nor use Secure Boot. But I thought you had to use MOK key when installing the nVidia driver with Secure Boot on. Try booting with UEFI Secure boot off.