# Mac laptop with Ubuntu stuck at boot after update

Tags: 22.04, laptop, mac, reboot

My laptop which has Ubuntu has stopped working after an update. I try to reboot the PC but it gets stuck at this screen [image: Ubuntu]

How could I fix it?

Comment: ACPI errors are not usually a problem. The lines that follow are typical of a normal and successful boot. What happens? Does the computer just hang doing nothing? Why have you tagged “Mac”? Has Ubuntu ever worked on this laptop or is it a new install?

Comment: The computer stays in this message, without doing anything. Ubuntu worked in my Mac perfectly. But since I made updates it stucks

Comment: I’ve never used Ubuntu on a Mac so probably cannot help you much. It would help others if you add the model of Mac to your question. Use the search function on this site to find similar questions. I’d guess your problem is likely to be a graphics driver

Comment: Now my Mac works, I boot it for x30 time, and now it works. But I have other issue, that the folders and files in desktop are disappeared, I can access them from terminal or from left bare, but I can't access them directly from desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)