# Kubuntu 23.04 no longer booting from Grub but boots using Advanced options?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

Several days ago Kubuntu stopped booting normally from the GRUB menu (Windows 10 dual boot).

At first I thought it was related to a Windows update but after repairing GRUB and also running `update-grub` from Kubuntu it still doesn't seem to work:

**Error Symptoms**

1. Let the default boot option of Kubuntu start after a 10 second countdown
2. Blank black screen is shown
3. Reboot
4. Select Advanced boot options --> choose another kernel version (normal) `6.2.0-23`
5. Boots into Kubtunu login screen ok

**Troubleshooting Steps**

- Removed all USB-C peripherals, disconnected second monitor
- Cleaned APT packages
- Changed Nvidia driver package to a older stable version (driver version 525)

Still the same issue persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is a longshot, but I personally would try to see if removing the nvidia drivers altogether would help. My computer could not boot today, despite working without issues yesterday. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` from https://askubuntu.com/a/974910/1644717 helped me resolving it. Trying to just update the nvidia driver from TTY did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Same issue here with Ubuntu 23.04, when I installed kernel 6.2.0-23, and I also use NVidia drivers.

Since I still have the kernel 6.2.0-20, I can still boot on it. I'm hoping a new NVidia driver (assuming that is the cause) will hopefully fix it.

Someone should add a test for that, and not allow the release, or create some incompatibility list, and mark the kernel as incompatible with NVidia driver.