# Ubuntu wont boot because of /dev/nvme0n1p7

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xubuntu

I tried to install the Nvidia drivers entered these commands
Sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Sudo apt install nvidia-gforce-530
Sudo reboot
And now when i want to power on my laptop from ubuntu boot it shows
/dev/nvmeon1p7: clean, 523421/611232 files, 9390991/24413952 blocks
And doesnt power on and stays on a black page
I have free space and when i want to fsck it say /de/nvme0n1p7 is mounted. e2fsck cannot continue aboerting
When i want to unmount that it says :
umount: /: target is busy
Its mountpoints is to : /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell

Comment: That is a nominal, non error message. It in fact tells you the partition is Ok. You must look to other causes for your issue.

Comment: You can only install one nVidia driver or you get conflicts. Did autoinstall install one version and then you installed 530 which was different? If so you must purge all installs and reinstall only one nVidia driver.  Can you press escape key just after vendor logo & get grub menu? Then boot recovery mode to get to terminal to fix drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)