# This screen shows everytime when i turn on my HP Laptop

Tags: boot

**My Ubuntu version - 23.04**

Please help me with this problem =>

As I turn on my HP laptop this screen shows:

[image: Booting image]

Comment: Does Ubuntu open afterwards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: No, I seen this, but this is not the solution of my answer

Comment: Yes it starts, but after a long wait.