# Cannot connect to wifi during dual-boot process

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, nvidia

I am trying to use dual-boot ubuntu 16 (because I need to use ROS Kinetic which requires ubuntu 16) on ThinkPad P15s laptop (windows 11). After downloading linux, and when rebooting I see a message saying like the following:[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYPWi.jpg)

I found this question forum (["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)) that talks about the same issue and tried most of the solutions mentioned but was able to make no progress. I tried the first suggestion and executed `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, and I got `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`. I also tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoninstall` and got `no drivers found for automatic installation`. I tried the 2nd suggestion and ran `sudo apt install gdm3` and got `package gdm3 has no installation candidate`. Then I went to the third suggestion and tried to connect to a network and faced several issues. My speculation that my previous command didn't work may come from the absence of an internet connection.

Anyways I found and similar question forum again (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/iwlist-interface-doesnt-support-scanning-ubuntu-lts-10-04) and went through the suggestions. I first executed `ifconfig` and got a following result:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atkcz.jpg)

Then I ran `iwconfig` and got a following result:
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B34G.jpg)

After this, I ran sudo ifconfig enp0s31f6 and it seemed to execute with no issue ( as the terminal was ready to accept a new terminal command) but when I ran `iwlist`, it was saying that the "interface doesn't support scanning".  [image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOnkQ.jpg) [image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt46O.jpg)

what should I do now...? I would very much appreciate the help.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Only *standard* support Ubuntu products/releases are on-topic here (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) which means Ubuntu 20.04 LTS & newer. Your system is off-topic here, but your question can be asked on SE *Unix & Linux* (see prior URL)