# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes on boot after installation

Tags: boot, 22.04, recovery-mode

*Note, I do not meet the problem described below with Ubuntu 20.04.*

**Problem:**
After a "successful" installation of **Ubuntu 22.04**.
I reboot my computer but it **freezes on a black screen** with this info written on it:

```
/dev/sda3: clean, 217199/2444624 files, 2561133/9765632 blocks
```

**Installation process:**
Below I provided information on how I installed Ubuntu 22.04.

Specs: x86_64, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060

1. Downloaded "ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso" on this website https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. Used "Rufus" to create a bootable USB (partition scheme MBR)
3. I used "Normal Installation" and "Install third-party software"
4. Installing Ubuntu I created 4 partitions (ext4 root, ext4 home, EFI system partition, swap)
5. Installed "successfully"
6. Reboot

After I rebooted, I faced the problem that I described earlier. The computer does not respond at all.

**My attempts at solving this problem:**
I tried to solve the problem by following the posts below, but they did not help. Mainly because I cannot do anything in recovery mode.

- ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)
- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

When I try to boot into recovery mode I get 2 options:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic (recovery mode)

Neither one works.

On the recovery Menu, I choose "root".
When I try to do `sudo apt update` system returns `W: Failed to fetch http:\\....`
I connected to the internet via a LAN cable. So, I'm pretty sure that computer has access to the Internet. The same applies to `sudo apt install ....`
Also, `sudo apt purge nvidia*` does not help, since I end up at the same screen on boot, and the computer freezes.

Comment: you should verify that the networkservices you are using are actually working. You can find out with sudo systemctl status <servicename>