# Error while booting Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, error-handling

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p1: clean, 405263/18317312 files, 9003492/73241856 blocks
[ 2.634096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[ 3.203295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[ 4.993134] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 6.515811] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
```

I am currently duel booting my laptop. I just installed Ubuntu and I had everything working fine until I installed `ROS2` and some packages (Autoware). After I finished my work, I powered off my PC. Three hours later I turned it on again and gave me this error. I don't wan't to install Ubuntu from the beginning since I need the files currently on the PC. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the computer boot eventually? In many cases it shows these messages during boot, but then the computer boots normally.

Comment: No its does boot, it stays on this screen forever. I tried to wait it out but I think it's just stuck on this screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: I believe it does, unfortunately, as I encounter this problem every time I finish downloading NVIDIA drivers. I will try this solution and let you know, Thank you for the help!